# column of ones adding to data frame in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

In Pandas, "DataFrame" I want to add column of ones in my Data Frame
I have tried certain things like trying to add
"df["c1"] = df["c1"].list(1)" but nothing works.
thank you

Comment: `df["c1"] = 1` is simpliest

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected ouput? From question is not clear what need.

Comment: I wanted to plot the 1 when the price is greater than previous close. And your method worked good.